# Is there any incoherent collimated monocromatic light source?

Tags: laser, coherence

I was looking for an incoherent monochromatic collimated light source. I know that if I shine a laser through some medium I'll partially lose the coherence but I will also sacrifice the collimation I was wondering if it exists an incoherent monochromatic collimated light source. Or any device to transform a collimated laser into an incoherent collimated light source. 
[image]
To my understanding, I can maintain the coherence even if the laser is not collimated, an incoherent collimated light source would be composed of photons with different phase shifts but collimated. Am I wrong?

Comment: What does "incoherent" mean in your application? Are you talking about _[temporal coherence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherence_(physics))_ or are you talking about _spatial coherence_? or both? If you don't what the light source to be spatially coherent, then can you explain in more detail what you mean by "collimated?" And, if you don't want the light source to be temporally coherent, then can you explain in more detail what you mean by "monochromatic?"

Comment: @SolomonSlow I've tried to clarify, I wanted to reduce the speckle noise of a system.

Comment: "Temporally coherent" means, a extremely narrow band of wavelengths. "Spatially coherent" means, in effect, that the light appears to come from (or can be made to appear to come from) an infinitessimally small point source.  If you have a light source that has both properties, then you will see speckles. An LED _is_ a narrow band source, but not as narrow as a laser. An LED _is_ a very small point-like source (but not as small and point-like as laser light.) If an LEDs bandwidth is too much for your application, and if the source is too big ("hard to collimate"), then...

Comment: ...There may not _be_ any light source that can meet all of your requirements. It sounds as if what you mean when you say "incoherent light" is, "coherent light that doesn't make speckles." That's a tall order.

Comment: @SolomonSlow thanks for your comments. When I say incoherent light I just want to say light with a variable phase difference, the fact that won't produce speckle is just a consequence.

Comment: Variable phase _difference_? Difference between what and what else? If you mean phase changes with time, then that's just variable phase. And basically, it's a statement about the bandwidth. So, you have a bandwidth requirement, and you're saying an LED is too broad and a laser is too narrow. I don't know what comes in between. Maybe something based on _[dichroic filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dichroic_filter)_ or dichroic mirrors. Good luck, but I think you need a more concrete, and more concise specification of your requirements--something with some _numbers_ in it.

Comment: From the comment you wrote, it seams similar to the "shadow projection" used in ultra-cold atom experiments. There exists other techniques to get partially rid of fringes, although one uses coherent light. Please note that such an answer would not fit your question.

Comment: Would line emission, say from hydrogen gas, be considered collimated and coherent?

Answer (score 2):

If light is monochromatic there is only one frequency $\omega$ (temporal coherence). If it is collimated there is only one direction of $\vec k$ (spatial coherence). Since $\omega = |\vec k| c$ this fixes the light to be a single plane wave and this is coherent in every sense.

Answer (score 0):

LEDs emit incoherent light.

Now you are asking for a collimated light. This means, that the beams spread at a limited rate (angle) at certain distance.

Now if you accept LEDs as collimated (relatively), then it is just about monochrome.

Now LEDs are actually not monochromatic, but the spectrum is narrow relatively to human vision, so it is technically monochromatic.

> > A collimated beam of light or other electromagnetic radiation has parallel rays, and therefore will spread minimally as it propagates. A perfectly collimated light beam, with no divergence, would not disperse with distance. Such a beam cannot be created, due to diffraction.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collimated_beam

> > The solid package of the LED can be designed to focus its light. Incandescent and fluorescent sources often require an external reflector to collect light and direct it in a usable manner. For larger LED packages total internal reflection (TIR) lenses are often used to the same effect. However, when large quantities of light are needed many light sources are usually deployed, which are difficult to focus or collimate towards the same target.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light-emitting_diode

So the answer is that if you want monochromatic light (and you accept that it has a narrow technical wavelength spectrum), and accept that the collimation is relative, then LEDs can work.

Comment: With LED I can't achieve the monocromaticy that I need (2-3 nm) and also the collimation of the LED  is not so easy

Comment: The spectrum would be technically monochromatic relative to human vision if you could get a color looking like monochromatic 510 nm from a LED. Currently, you can't, and it has a lot to do with the fact that 510 nm is a point where human eyes can easily distinguish very close wavelengths (e.g. 2 nm difference will result in a noticeable difference in color). This is reflected on high curvature of the chromaticity diagram at that location.